# Set Taxonomy with site scripts on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm trying to make a script for SharePoint site designs using JSON to create a list and set taxonomy field values.

Is it possible to set taxonomy with site scripts to lists and columns ?

Answer (score 0):

So far you cannot create a **Taxonomy** or **Choice** field types, **Views**, **Pages** and **Page content**.

With site scripts you can :

- Create a very simple list
- Apply theme
- Apply logo to communications site
- Create site with or without external sharing
- Add links to navigation

> **Note :** Site designs and site scripts are in the evaluation phase and are subject to change. - "Microsoft".